# Javascript data loading issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, highcharts

I am building a visualization consisting of a dateslider (jQDateRangeSlider), 6 drop downs and a  trendgraph (using highcharts.js) 
So there are in total 7 filters( 6 drop downs + dateslider ) according to which the dataset changes and the chart dynamically changes for each selection.

But, there are many combinations(of selections) for which there is no data.
In this case, I would like to display all the filters (dateslider+ dropdowns) and instead of chart, I would like to display " No data present " or any text instead of data
OR
If possible, I could also display the charts with values-0 for the entire range (although in this even the range is not defined as there is no dataset, so I can take default entire range)

For the first idea, I was trying:

```
function printpgtyp(data)
{   
    console.log(data);
    if (data.length > 0)
    {   
        dataset = data;
        p(dataset);
    }
    else
    {   q();    }

}

function q()
{ 
    document.write(" Unavailable data ");
}

function p(data)
{ 
    //All my visualization code
}
```

So, this works but it takes me to another page and shows the text, I don't want this.

I would like to view all my filters and render a text message saying this selection has no data, so that the user can select a selection which will have data and continue with the visualization

Is there a way to do this?

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `document.write` wipes the screen, which might be the simulation of it going to a new page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `document.write`, add the text to a div element:

```
function q()
{ 
    var div = document.getElementById("elementId");
    div.innerHTML = "this selection has no data";
}
```

Comment: Great this works, I am replacing the div element of my highcharts with the new text and it works. Also, can you tell me how I can edit this text and place it in the centre and modify font etc inside q() and not in the div element (as it's my main highcharts div also)

Comment: Glad, I could help. I would recommend adding a class in your q-method and do the styling in a css file. ;)

Comment: Perfect, makes sense, will do that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [`noData`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#noData) plugin for Highcharts? In case of empty dataset just call `series.setData([])` to remove previous points.